# How can I get logback to write to a log file outside of my jar?

Tags: java, logging, jar

I have built a jar file, and inside it is the `logback.xml` config file which looks like this:

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>output.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ERRORS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>errors.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="error.logger" level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="ERRORS" />
</logger>

<logger name="info.logger" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ERRORS"/>
</root>
```

However, when I run my jar like this `java -jar myapp.jar` it never writes to any log file. What am I missing? Is it possible to write to a log file outside of the jar using logback? How do I configure this?

Comment: Hi jcm, I hope you could solve this issue. I am facing the same problem. Can you please share your solution here?